# Hypothesis testing to discriminate between two renewal processes

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, neyman-pearson-lemma

> We have time [0,T] to observe a renewal point process, where the inter-renewal timings are i.i.d, and then decide whether the observation is according to a renewal process in which the pdf of inter-renewal process is  $p(x)$ or $q(x)$.
>
> We want to do this hypothesis testing in such a way that the sum of error probabilities (type I error and type II error) is minimum. What is the sum of error probabilities in this case?

I have solved this problem for the case that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two exponential distributions so the renewal processes are Poisson. Can you please help to solve it for the general case?